# Responding with a static file in viewer

Tags: django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I'am developing a django application using Apache+wsgi_mod. I defined a simple **viewer** returning user's image. But in case the user hasn't any picture I want to render a static standard image (dependent on sex), stored in my **static** folder. I know I could use static.serve() but django documentation dissuades this. **How to serve a static file from a viewer?**

UPDATE:

viewer is a method defined in views.py (img below e.g.)

I might want to return HttpResponseRedirect() to my static content. But than I need absolute URL.

I need this because I've got something like that:

```
def img(request, usr_id):
    usr_image = get_usr_image(usr_id)
    if usr_image == None:
        return respond_with_standard_image()
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/jpg')
        response.write(usr_image)
        return response
```

and want to respond with a standard user image.

UPDATE2:

I can do something like that:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://' + request.get_host() + settings.STATIC_URL + 'img/125px-Silver_-_male.png')
```

but I'm not satisfied.

Comment: What? What is a "viewer"? Why is serving a static image from there any different than serving your standard CSS/JS/images?

Answer (score 0):

Django should'nt be involved into rendering images or any other static file. You should put your users images in a custom directory, and serving it directly with your web server.

Rendering a different image if the original file does not exists can easily be achieved with a rewrite rule.

Comment: Well, u're right. But it doesn't work in my case. I'm getting those images from a database through other layer using special api, so I have to involve django.

Comment: I don't understand. In your example, and your 2nd update, you don't serve any image from a database, since you're doing a redirect. Which data comes from your db exactly?

Comment: Only real images come from db. Other (anonymous, standard) images i put myself into static/ folder, so I can do a redirect.

Comment: Then, you only have two possibilities. Either you serve the static file from your view, which is ugly but avoids a redirect. Or you do the redirect, and serve it with apache. Storing files in db is ugly anyway.

Comment: I know it's ugly, but I have to adapt. I'll try to load those images in case of 404 using ajax inside template.